# AppStore rejected app for Third Party In App Purchase IOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

We have third party payment gateway on our application and apple rejected our app stating we need IAP.

Our app is supposed to be a coaching/career/testseries related app i.e. something like where you can buy content to study and practice on demand

Here's our business model and I need insights on how to approach it with IAP

Our platform let's user buy "x tests for y amount of money that expires in z days"

If you have used all "x" tests then you can check the new available plans and purchase them and similarly if you have passed "z" days.

These plans are non-renewable cause the tests are limited in nature and the pricing, no of tests and expiry keeps on changing depending on the market.

How do we approach this case?
Also the added complexity is also adding third party payment capability which in this case seems almost impossible but I'd like to ask

Answer (score 0):

You cant use 3rd party payment gateway if the goods are digital.

your options:

1. make an in-app currency (coins) like games, so the user can buy a package of coins (for example 1000 coin) using app store IAP, then use it to buy stuff in your app as if it was 3rd party payment gateway.
2. show the different programs that the user can purchase and tell them to buy them from your website (but you cant put a direct link to your website in app) you can see how Spotify handels this in its iOS app install Spotify App and see how they do not even link to the main website of the service from the app because this is not allowed.

you can only show description and tell people to go to your website without linking to your website.

[image: screenshot]